# Microsoft AdControl error: No ad available. No additional information

Tags: windows-store-apps, ads

I have a Windows app which I haven't updated for a while. This app contains a few ads and since 8 days the app revenue has dropped to 0 and the adspace is black. If I debug my app the AdControl produces the following error:

```
Microsoft AdControl error: No ad available. No additional information
```

I have checked with Microsoft and I am using the correct Advertising SDK. The strange thing is that I don't see my AdUnits in the developer portal anymore. If I create a new adunit and add this to my app I get the same error. I have contacted Microsoft about this and they say some things have changed on their end but if they escalate this it could take up to 4 weeks. So that is kind of useless.

So I was wondering if anybody else ran in to this issue lately and maybe know a solution to this problem?

Comment: Could you share your application Id and Ad Unit Id here so that we can try contacting the related team to see if they could help?

Answer (score 0):

So I received an email from Microsoft stating the following:

> Thank you for creating the new ad unit and testing it in your app.
>   Since the integration of pubCenter with DevCenter, only newly created
>   ad units show in reporting. It’s a known issue and the solution from
>   the ads team is to create new ad units, so that they will show on the
>   dashboard. I know this is not ideal and that fact has been noted.
>   Occasionally an older ad unit will still show in the dashboard (for
>   example, today I checked all of your ad units and was only able to see
>   those for two of your apps on the advertising
>   performance page. If any of your other ad units were created post Dev
>   Center/pubCenter integration, please let me know and for those I can
>   escalate for those ad units. Otherwise, the correct page to view your
>   ad units reporting moving forward is here
>   https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/analytics/adperformance.
>   Also, only ad units created after pubCenter/Dev Center integration
>   will show under the individual product (app name > monetization >
>   monetize with ads) as well, so this is expected behavior. Again, I am
>   sorry for any inconvenience. I’m still awaiting an update from the
>   investigating team about the ads not showing for your app. I
>   understand that this is causing you to lose revenue and it’s my goal
>   to see this resolved for you as quickly as possible. I’ll check in
>   with you again the beginning of next week.

**For anybody else who ran into this same issue:** Apparently Microsoft made a bit of a mess when integrating pubcenter with devcenter causing app revenue to suddenly drop to zero. I will update this post next week, hopefully everything works fine by then.

**Update:** I have created new adunits and updated my app but still no revenue, for 13 days now. Microsoft really screwed up on this one, is unable to fix the problem and support is slow and doesn't know anything...

**Update:** another week later, and Microsoft still hasn't found the issue, absolutely hopeless...